# ansiToUtf8 doesnt work with converted Delphi XE projects from Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-7, oracle9i, delphi-xe

There is a Oracle 9 db with CL8MSWIN1251 codepage setting and Delphi XE with some edit fields.

I need to convert project made in Delphi 7 to Delphi Xe project to use and able to see UTF8 data.

So I opened dpr file using Delphi XE and it converted automatically to dproj. But when I try to insert into db some data, I got question symbols ("?") instead of some utf8 chars.
I tried to convert data from Edits (Tedit) using ansitoUTF8(edit1.text). And it doesn't work.
Then I started a new project in XE, quickly added some edits to check ansitoutf8 function and it works well and inserts data to same db and into same table.

There is one rule: I cannot change codepage setting in db.

```
begin
  adoquery1.close;
  adoquery1.sql.text:='insert into table (data1,data2) values ('+#39+ansitoUTF8(edit1.text)+#39+','+#39+ansitoUTF8(edit2.text)+#39+')';
  adoquery1.execsql;
end;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you aware that sql.text is a string and thus resembles a UnicodeString in D2009? Whatever you do before, it will be converted to unicode when assigned to sql.text. You may get around this by using parameters for the query (which I would recommend anyway), setting the DataType to ftString.

Comment: You can't change the database codepage, but are the tables under your control? Check the nvarchar type: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90120/ch4_dep.htm

Answer (score 1):

CL8MSWIN1251 is not an UTF-8 code page, is Oracle implementation of Windows 1251 (Cyrillic) codepage. Delphi XE uses always UTF-16. Oracle database and client are able to perform character set conversion. You should set the NLS_LANG parameter of your client/session properly. If you don't want to change the client code page, you can issue an ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = ... at logon to change it for that session only. For an XE Unicode application with an Oracle 9i database, you can use AL16UTF16 on the client side to tell client data are in UTF-16 format and let Oracle perform its conversions.

PS: code like

```
#39+ansitoUTF8(edit1.text)+#39+...
```

is the best way to introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities. You should use bind variables, or at least use functions like QuotedStr/AnsiQuotedStr that will ensure strings stays string and don't become SQL commands in the wrong hands.

Comment: @ldsandon, there's no such thing as a "UTF-8 code page". UTF8 is a notation for Unicode text, code pages are used for ANSI strings to create a mapping between the ANSI char set and what would now be called a subset of Unicode.

Comment: @Cosmin: just in Windows *code page* 65001 is UTF-8... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Idsandon: you say: `"CL8MSWIN1251 is not an UTF-8 code page"`; That assumes some code pages are UTF-8, while `CL8MSWIN1251` is not. It assumes there are multiple `UTF-8` code pages, when in fact UTF8 is a notation, not a code page. The fact that Windows uses code page 65001 to handle UTF8 data doesn't make a difference: The `1:1` mapping between code page 65001 and UTF8 is Windows's trick.

Comment: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
UTF-8 is a character encoding/character set, and thereby a *code page*.
Ok, my assertion could be misread (of course there is not need of multiple UTF-8 code pages).

Comment: Ok, so giving UTF-8 a code page number is not only a Windows trick, but none the less UTF-8 is a notation, or a "transformation", not a code page. You should edit the answer to remove any possible confusion.

Comment: Isn't "code page" a Windows/Microsoft trick by definition? Aren't "code page" some other kind of transformation? You could loose Unicode glyphs with code pages, whereas UTF-8/UTF-16 will preserve all range. But both are "transformation" pattern. As ldsandon wrote, UTF-8 code page number is 65001, as for Delphi: `UTF8String = string(65001)` uses these code pages internal in its new `string` type.

Comment: He could also see 3.9 of http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404, "The Unicode Standard supports three **character encoding** forms: UTF-32, UTF-16, and UTF-8." The only difference is that Unicode encodings maps a byte sequence to a Unicode code point which in turn is mapped to a glyph, while other encodings maps a byte sequence directly to a glyph.
BTW: *code page* is an IBM "trick". It was used in IBM OSes before MS used it.

Comment: and... there is no unique adequation between a glyph and an Unicode code point... for instance, you can have diacritics and such which will alter the next code point in the Unicode sequence in order to change the resulting glyph...

Answer (score 1):

There is a backward compatibility break in Delphi XE with `AnsiToUTF8()` function, in fact in the `Utf8Encode()` function it calls.

In Delphi XE, it returns a `RawByteString` kind of string. So you'll have to force the result type into `UTF8String`. Like this: `UTF8String(ansitoUTF8(...)`

But I guess this perhaps is not your issue.

In your code:

```
adoquery1.sql.text:='insert into table (data1,data2) values ('+#39+ansitoUTF8(edit1.text)+#39+','+#39+ansitoUTF8(edit2.text)+#39+')';
```

The `sql.text` expression is a `UnicodeString`, so you'll have explicit conversion made by the Delphi XE compiler in your concatenation expression.

Does the following line work?

```
adoquery1.sql.text:='insert into table (data1,data2) values ('+#39+edit1.text+#39+','+#39+edit2.text+#39+')';
```

It should work under XE, and the conversion into UTF8 should be made by the VCL from raw `UnicodeString`.

Comment: +1. I'd actually declare a type like this `type Ansi1251 = type AnsiString(1251)` and then cast the use `Ansi1251(AnsiToUTF8(...))`; This would treat the result of `AnsiToUTF8` as text in ANSI text with the `1251` code page, so all the following conversions to Unicode and back to `1251` will conserve the byte values.

Comment: Don't do that. Let Oracle perform its conversions. Configure Oracle correctly and there's no need to go back and forth ANSI codepages everytime you need to write data. Oracle knows more about national language support than Delphi ever did.

Comment: @Idsandon, as I understand this problem, the database column is already defined to use code page 1251, and that can't change, but the OP wants to put international characters in there; The OP wants to first encode the international text as UTF8, that push it into the DB column unchanged, and (I assume) do the conversion manually when text is read from the DB. Since the result of AnsiToUtf8 is used in a string concatenation, the RAW bytes are converted back to Unicode, and my guess is that the conversion maps to some Unicode code points that don't have an equivalent in Code page 1251. [...]

Comment: [...] forcing the result of AnsiToUTF8 to be interpreted as `Ansi1251` guarantees the conversion to Unicode returns chars that can be represented in the Ansi1251 code page; Since the conversion for Ansi1251 to Unicode to Ansi1251 is guaranteed to be lossless, Oracle will conserve the UTF8 text (will not replace anything with question marks). Since UTF8 was conserved, it can be converted back to Unicode at will.

Comment: Anything it does at the Delphi level will go through Oracle conversion at the client/database level, depending on NLS settings. If he's trying to *hack* the database sending UTF-8 data in another encoding, it will work only if and only if the client and datatabase are set the same way, and will yeld strange result in any other situation. It will also have strange behaviours when indexing/querying data, unless a pure binary collation is used, which again could yeld strange result. Also CL8MSWIN1251 is is single byte, while UTF-8 is not, leading to more issues as well.